# How to link www sub-domain to specific vhost DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, web-server, ubuntu-12.04, virtualhost

Server Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 | Apache 2.2

I have disabled the default vhost configuration using `a2dissite default` and deleted the default file from `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`. I have 3 domains pointed at the VPS at DigitalOcean and I've added CNAME records for `www` linked to `domain.com.` (with the trailing dot).

Theis is the current setup:

- domain1.com : http://pastie.org/9457734
- domain2.com : http://pastie.org/9457732
- domain3.com : No vhost defined, but pointed at VPS

Navigating to domain1.com serves the intended DocumentRoot, so does domain2.com. However, navigating to **www**.domain1.com serves the DocumentRoot of domain2.com (this is the problem). This doesn't seem to happen with **www**.domain2.com which serves the correct path. domain3.com which has no vhost created also mysteriously serves the content from domain2.com

If I delete the `www` CNAME records, the links with www do not work after DNS propagation. I have seen suggestions to add a `ServerAlias` directive in the vhost files. When I add such directives, Apache errors out with the following:

> "ScriptAlias takes two arguments, a fakename and a realname"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have not entered the actual domain names here to avoid bots picking them up, but they are available at the pastie.org links above. You can try accessing the server yourself to understand the situation better. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there,  Can you include your httpd.conf and vhosts.conf if you have one?

Comment: @krisFR, I'm guessing the links in your post will get indexed. Care to mask them with arc.com.ng instead. Yes, arc.com.ng and the `www` equivalent works, but **www** .hrsys.com.ng (actual domain masked) points to arc's DocumentRoot. Do you understand me?

Comment: @DavidEisen I checked under /etc/apache2/ - the `httpd.conf` file there is empty (0 bytes).

Comment: Ok sorry, made a mistake. What if you replace `<VirtualHost *:80>` by `<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>` (where xx is the ip address) for each domain ?

Comment: @krisFR Both domain names are pointed at the same VPS, so they share the same IP address (104.131.254.52). With both domain names sharing the same IP address, wouldn't the default wildcard suffice?

Comment: @KrisFR I went ahead and added the IP address, after reloading/restarting apache, I got an error: "[warn] virtual host IP:port overlaps with IP:port, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive."

Comment: Yes, in this case you will need to define `NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx`. But, to be honnest, i am not sure it will solve your initial issue...

Comment: I resolved this by adding ServerAlias directives in the vhosts.

Comment: ok great, but you told in your initial question that you had an error doing this...

Comment: @KrisFR Yes, I did. I don't know why it didn't work because I got the error I posted earlier when I tried. Thank you very much for your help. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as an accepted solution to help others who end up here when searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you get this error when using `ServerAlias`, however this should be the way to go.

From the [docmuentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#serveralias) :

> The `ServerAlias` directive sets the alternate names for a host, for
>   use with name-based virtual hosts

This is actually what you are doing, as you have defined `www.hrsys.com.ng` as an alias (CNAME) in your DNS for `hrsys.com.ng`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The ServerAlias eventually worked, however I had to create a CNAME record for `WWW` pointing to mydomain.com. (with the trailing dot).

Comment: Of course you had to do so, this is what my last sentence says, but i edit to be more clear ;)